# How to remove title from box in orgChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, orgchart

How to remove title from the `box` i want only content to be shown.

i have searched a  lot but did not find any solution.

i'm using **orgChart** : https://github.com/dabeng/OrgChart

for **eg**  `general manager` will be box without **title**  `Lao Lao`

here is demo: https://codepen.io/dabeng/pen/zBNbqV

```js
'use strict';

(function($){

  $(function() {

    var datascource = {
      'name': 'Lao Lao',
      'title': 'general manager',
      'children': [
        { 'name': 'Bo Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Li Jing', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept' },
            { 'name': 'Li Xin', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'product-dept',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'To To', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
                { 'name': 'Fei Fei', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' },
                { 'name': 'Xuan Xuan', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'pipeline1' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        { 'name': 'Su Miao', 'title': 'department manager', 'className': 'middle-level',
          'children': [
            { 'name': 'Pang Pang', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept' },
            { 'name': 'Hei Hei', 'title': 'senior engineer', 'className': 'rd-dept',
              'children': [
                { 'name': 'Xiang Xiang', 'title': 'UE engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' },
                { 'name': 'Dan Dan', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' },
                { 'name': 'Zai Zai', 'title': 'engineer', 'className': 'frontend1' }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };

    var oc = $('#chart-container').orgchart({
      'data' : datascource,
      'nodeContent': 'title'
    });

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
#chart-container {
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 420px;
  border: 2px dashed #aaa;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.orgchart {
  background: #fff; 
}
.orgchart td.left, .orgchart td.right, .orgchart td.top {
  border-color: #aaa;
}
.orgchart td>.down {
  background-color: #aaa;
}
.orgchart .middle-level .title {
  background-color: #006699;
}
.orgchart .middle-level .content {
  border-color: #006699;
}
.orgchart .product-dept .title {
  background-color: #009933;
}
.orgchart .product-dept .content {
  border-color: #009933;
}
.orgchart .rd-dept .title {
  background-color: #993366;
}
.orgchart .rd-dept .content {
  border-color: #993366;
}
.orgchart .pipeline1 .title {
  background-color: #996633;
}
.orgchart .pipeline1 .content {
  border-color: #996633;
}
.orgchart .frontend1 .title {
  background-color: #cc0066;
}
.orgchart .frontend1 .content {
  border-color: #cc0066;
}

#github-link {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 10px;
  font-size: 3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/js/jquery.orgchart.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/orgchart/2.1.3/css/jquery.orgchart.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="chart-container"></div>
```

Comment: Please place the code IN the question, as a link that may go away and thus become a useless dead link here.

Comment: please check i have edited my question

Comment: Great!  Now I can up vote it :)

Comment: i'm looking something like this don't know how to achieve https://rawgit.com/dabeng/OrgChart/master/demo/edit-chart.html

Comment: You want that "visual" or the "edit" functionality?  Right click that page and view that page source perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

You can go with above solutions - I think you might want those symbols instead of title.

This code will remove only title.

```
.title {
    text-indent: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$(".title").hide();
```

OR

```
$(".title").css("display", "none");
```

Using Css :

```
.title {
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about `font-size`.

```
.title {
    font-size: 0 !important;
}
```

Or you could just do:

```
.title {
  color: transparent !important;
}
```